# Android WebView not loading url SameSite=None

Tags: android, cookies, http-headers, android-webview

I'm trying to load a web (Ex. www.google.com) but the webview throughs the next message to the console:

> A cookie associated with a resource at http://google.com/ was set with
>   `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will
>   only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked
>   `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under
>   Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source:
>   https://www.google.com/

I don't know how to fix this issue. I'm doing the next code to load an url, how I can fix this?

```
private void initWebView(String url){

        webViewTvWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(new WebView(getActivity()));
        webViewTvWeakReference.get().setId(TV_WEB_VIEW_ID);
        webViewTvWeakReference.get().setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, new Paint());
        webViewTvWeakReference.get().setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        webViewTvWeakReference.get().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.lightBlueBackgroundColor));
        webViewTvWeakReference.get().requestFocusFromTouch();

        setUpWebSettings(webViewTvWeakReference.get());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        }

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict");

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            webViewTvWeakReference.get().setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    handler.proceed();
                }
            });
        }

        if(!url.isEmpty()){
            webViewTvWeakReference.get().loadUrl(url, headers);
        }else{
            webViewTvWeakReference.get().loadUrl("about:blank", headers);
        }

        webViewTvWeakReference.get().pauseTimers();     // WebView timers consumes a lot off CPU
        webViewTvWeakReference.get().resumeTimers();    // Pause and Resume timers fix this behaivour

    }
```

I've added the next line to the headers, but stills not working.

```
headers.put("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This warning is specifically for the cookie from `google.com`, so you are not responsible for setting its attributes. The team at Google needs to apply the relevant attribute to their cookies in order to resolve this warning.

In the event that you do have any cookies that need to be sent in a cross-site / third-party context, then they need be set using:

```
Set-Cookie: foo=bar; SameSite=None; Secure
```

However, at this stage, this warning should be purely informational. The cookie is still being sent with the request and you should not be seeing any issues with the behaviour of the site within the WebView.

These new restrictions will become the default in Chrome 80, however they will not apply to WebViews for the time being.

You can learn more about these upcoming changes at https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained.

Additionally, you can check if your particular browser or WebView is implementing the new behaviour by pointing it at https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me. If that matrix is all green, then your browser **is** implementing the new restrictions. If there is any red or orange on the board, then your browser **is not** yet applying the new defaults.

Comment: after the message "A cookie associated with a resource at http://google.com/ was set with SameSite=None but without Secure..." the webview stills blank and no page is loaded. I don't know what to do, I'm testing with google.com.

Comment: I built a little test site here: https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me that will show you what your default behaviour your browser is applying. If it's all green, the new restrictions are being applied. If it's not all green, then those warnings are not having any effect on the functionality of the site.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the remote cookie stteings who is causing the message to appear. It seems the issue is local! Have the same problem with theses annoying messages!